# Gradle on IntelliJ Folder Structure

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I need help including Gradle in an already existing project.

My main problem is that the project structure is not the "default" Gradle structure. I also have three projects in my Idea Project, which makes it more difficult.

**My projects:**

- Client
- Server
- Shared *(as in Shared Code between Client and server)*

**This is my folder structure:**

- MyApplication

  - src

    - com

      - elmac

        - client
        - server
        - shared

So I get nice URL Style packets for my classes. *(i.e.: com.elmac.client.Main)*

**My concrete question**

Where do I have to put which gradle files, and what do I have to write in the files, in order to create two .JAR files (Client and Server depend from shared --> Shared does not need a jar file).

I got really confused with the dozens of tutorials, each containing similar structures that are not similar to mine. And I havent figured out how to include my projects (I dont even know where to put which file on this project structure!)

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand your reasoning "So I get nice URL Style packets for my classes." You would get that even if you split them into the subprojects and use a more standard directory structure. You can then have both client and server subproject depend on the shared subproject (either as jars or directly as with the project dependency).

However to answer your question, you can start by defining different source sets in the build.gradle:

```
sourceSets {
    client {
        java {
            srcDirs = ["$projectDir/src"]
            include '**/client/**'
        }
...
}
```

These will then be compiled into separate directories in the build dir. Then you can build your jars from these source sets:

```
task clientJar(type: Jar) {
    from sourceSets.client.output
}
```

You might run into problems with IntelliJ because it can have only one output directory for main and one for tests in each module, so you can't use IntelliJ compile & run anymore (e.g. when running single unit tests), you will have to run everything using gradle tasks.

Comment: I come from eclipse where you can have real subprojects, as in different source folders. How could I have achieved the URL-Style packets without putting all the folders for that? I don't know what is a standard directory structure. Thanks for your answer, I will try it out right away!

Comment: How can I make the dependency of client and server with the shared subproject (best would be as project dependency)? I get errors because my client and server dont find the code of shared. It contains just utility so it "doesn't find property output on source set shared".

Comment: You can have dependencies between sourcesets, but I really think you are trying to re-invent a wheel. Still don't get "URL-Style packets"

Comment: I learned that in Java you should name your packages like a reversed URL. If you work in Google your Package name could be com.google.myname.controller.Main.class. How would I make a dependency between sourceSets? It probably is with dependencies{} but where do I place this? Do you know how I can name my packages like an URL, without having to create a folder structure like I have? Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I see. But you can have three projects creating three jars with dependencies between projects and still keep this package (not packets) structure. The folder structure comes mostly from maven best practices: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html

Comment: I had this working on Maven, but I heard it's against Mavens modularity principles to have more than one Jar from the same Source-Code. So I thrashed Maven and wanted to go with Gradle...